# Running JUnit tests from Terminal

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I have some JUnit tests that are running in IntelliJ just fine. However, I need to run these same tests from the terminal. My problem is, no matter what I do, I get an error that says:

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: com.myCompany.MyTests
```

I do not know why it is not working. In an attempt to run the unit tests from the command-line, I'm running the following:

```
java -cp /Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA\ 13.app/lib/junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.myCompany.MyTests
```

However, the only thing I see is the error listed above. I keep running this command up and down my source directory. Yet, no matter what I can't get any tests to run from the command-line. Yet, they run just fine from within IntelliJ. How do I get my tests to run from the command-line in the same way that they run from within IntelliJ? Is there some way I can view the actual command(s) that IntelliJ runs when running JUnit?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere there is a directory or jar that holds that 'com' directory that is the root of your application's package structure (com/myCompany). That directory or jar needs to be added to the classpath through the -cp flag you are already using.

So say as an example that the class is in:

/workspaces/myproject/bin/com/myCompany/MyTests.class

then you need to add the /workspaces/myproject/bin directory to the classpath.

Comment: And not part of the answer but just a general remark: you would be wise to put some further study in how to use the command line tools (java, javac and jar) outside of an IDE to compile, run and package stuff. You have been pampered by your IDE too much :)

Comment: I totally agree with the pampering part. I've been moving from .NET to Java and I'm slowly learning. How do I include multiple class paths via the command line?

Comment: Depends on the OS you're using. Google "Java classpath" to find out.